# Terminology - ECR repo uri vs ECR repo name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

In the below json received after talking to AWS ECR end point service:

```
{
    "repository": {
        "repositoryArn": "arn:aws:ecr:us-west-2:11122233334444:repository/some_app_image",
        "registryId": "11122233334444",
        "repositoryName": "some_app_image",
        "repositoryUri": "11122233334444.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/some_app_image",
        "createdAt": 11111111554.0,
        "imageTagMutability": "MUTABLE",
        "imageScanningConfiguration": {
            "scanOnPush": false
        }
    }
}
```

---

after running command: `aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names some_app_image`

How to term `11122233334444.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`? Is it an ECR end point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would refer to it as your registry URL. More information on terminology at the [ECR user docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html)

Answer (score 0):

The value in `repositoryUri` is what you would use in a command like `docker pull`. So in this example you would say `docker pull 11122233334444.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/some_app_image` to download your image.

Comment: How to term `11122233334444.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: repositoryUri includes repository name. For example: `11122233334444.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/some_app_image`

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking. That would be the domain, but I wouldn't really refer to that directly. You never know if the next repository will have the same domain structure.

Comment: Jason is right as well. but I would call it ECR regional service endpoint :)

Comment: The only issue I have with calling it a regional endpoint is that most endpoints in AWS that are regional are not also account specific. This endpoint not only contains region but also account.